# Why Oracle it's running this (wrong) query

Tags: sql, oracle

Why Oracle it's running this (wrong) query?

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID = 1ORDER BY ID;
```

without a **space** between `1` and `ORDER`

Comment: Because it can :). In Oracle a variable name or identifier starts with underscore("_") or letters. So, for `1order` it knows there is no identifier, it must be a number, so it tries to get the number and separate the rest and it succeed.

Comment: The question is why execute this query without a space between "1" and "ORDER".

Comment: Investigate whichever tool sent the query to the database.

Comment: Y try to query **SELECT*FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID = 1ORDER BY ID;** and works too.

Comment: feature or bug? dabate is open!

Comment: SO is not a site for debates, but that's clearly a feature.

Comment: FWIW: Postgres and SQL Server accept this as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle a variable name or identifier starts with underscore("_") or letters. So, for `1order`, the interpreter knows there is no identifier, it must be a number, so it tries to get the number and separate the rest and succeeds.

Comment: But it's a **unstandard** query language?

Comment: Oracle SQL is not fully compliant with standard sql (ANSI?) nor any other DBMS. There are specific features or missing features in every product.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the **explain plan**, you can see that Oracle could resolve the filter predicate, and the query is considered valid.

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT * FROM OE.CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 232ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID;

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4238351645

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |              |     1 |   177 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CUSTOMERS    |     1 |   177 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | CUSTOMERS_PK |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("CUSTOMER_ID"=232)

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So, optimizer could identify it as **access("CUSTOMER_ID"=232)**

Comment: Yes, but it is the *parser* who validate the query.

Comment: Yes, during the parse phase to check the syntax and semantics.

Comment: The explain plan has nothing to do with interpreter which parse the query string.

Comment: I just showed that the query has qualified and that the filter was properly applied which can be seen in the explain plan.